# Harmonic Oscillator Trial Wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

I was learning today about trial wave functions for a harmonic oscillator.

We learnt that the solution to Schrödinger equation for a harmonic oscillator is a Gaussian curve, i.e.
$$
f(x) = e^{-x^2} . 
$$

Testing a trial function such as:

$$
\psi = N_{0}e^{-ax^2}
$$

where $x$ is position gave 
$$
\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2} = N_{0} \ (4a^2x^2 - 2a)\cdot e^{-ax^{2}} .
$$

Applying this to Schrödinger's equation using reduced mass $\mu$
$$
-N_{0} \cdot \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}(4a^2x^2 - 2a)e^{-ax^2}+ \frac{1}{2}kx^2\ \cdot N_{0}e^{-ax^2} = E\ \cdot \ N_{0}e^{-ax^2}
$$
simplified to
$$
- \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}(4a^2x^2 - 2a)+ \frac{1}{2}kx^2 = E.
$$

The lecturer mentioned that as the total energy $E$ was constant, 
$E$ cannot be dependent on position $x$ which made sense from studies on Harmonic Motion.

Then he continued to state:

> We therefore have a solution to the Schrödinger equation if the terms in $x$ are equal and opposite and cancel.

Suddenly the equation becomes:
$$ 
\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} \cdot 4a^2x^2 =  \frac{1}{2}kx^2 
$$
and solving for $a$:
$$
a = \frac{\sqrt{k\mu}}{2\hbar}.
$$
My question is how did the equation
$$
- \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}(4a^2x^2 - 2a)+ \frac{1}{2}kx^2\ = E
$$
suddenly transform into 
$$ 
\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} \cdot 4a^2x^2 =  \frac{1}{2}kx^2 
$$
in just one line?

Comment: The answer by LonelyProf is right, but just to help... The equation didn't "transform". The operation is not the same thing as changing, for example, $x+2=2x-1$ to $x=3$. This is actually a new equation based on the reasoning you give. In other words, it's not like we changed the original equation by setting $a=E=0$. It's a new equation.

Comment: "We learnt that the solution to Schrödinger equation for a harmonic oscillator is a Gaussian curve." Keep in mind that this is *a* solution, not *the* solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic point is that the equation involving $E$ is an [*identity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(mathematics)), which must hold for *all* values of $x$, not just particular values of $x$. So, all the $x$-dependent parts must cancel identically. Sometimes, identities are distinguished from simple equations by using the symbol $\equiv$ rather than $=$.

Slightly more generally, if you 
bring all the terms onto the left and rearrange your equation into the form of
a *polynomial* identity
$$
C_0 + C_1 x + C_2 x^2 + \ldots + C_n x^n \equiv 0
$$
which must hold for all values of $x$, then it follows that *all* the coefficients $C_i$ must vanish. You can show this by setting $x=0$ (hence $C_0=0$); then by differentiating with respect to $x$ and setting $x=0$ (hence $C_1=0$); and so on.